# Como encontrar un valor dentro de un array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo el siguiente array en JavaScript, de objetos. Son mesas que estan unidas entre si fisicamente y la manera de representarlo es que cada mesa tiene una propiedad **join_with** que contiene un string de id de las mesas a las que esta unida y separados por comas.
Ejemplo, la mesa
{"table":{"id":1,"name":"Mesa 1","capacity":4,**"join_with":"2"**}}
esta unida a la mesa con id 2 porque asi lo indica su campo join_with.

ARRAY CON MESAS

```
let arrayTest=[
{"table":{"id":1,"name":"Mesa Alta","capacity":4,**"join_with":"2"**}},
{"table":{"id":2,"name":"Mesa media","capacity":6,**"join_with":"null"**}},
{"table":{"id":3,"name":"Mesa baja","capacity":10,**"join_with":"1,2"**}}
]
```

Como puedo recorriendo el array devolver(Puede ser por consola) los nombres de las mesas con las que cada mesa esta unida, utilizando para esto los id join_with:

Comment: Como trataste de encontrar el elemento?, agregalo por favor, saludos.

Comment: Hola Jorge, he probado de mil maneras pero sigo estancado donde mismo, pido la ayuda porque no tengo ideas ya de como buscar, solo necesito que me explicaran al menos como podria tener esos resultados.

Comment: @WilfredoPalmaPérez añade el código que estas utilizando para encontrar el elemento por favor.

Comment: No tengo ningun codigo para encontrar el elemento, eso es lo que estoy pidiendo. Lo unico que tengo es un array de objetos que es el que les muestro.
Los ejemplos que les pongo debajo es lo que necesitaria obtener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dejo una solucion que yo implemente, pero pueden existir muchas mas variantes.

CodeSanbox --> [Codigo](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-star-znqsz?file=/src/index.js:248-1011)

```js
const tableRelatedNames = () => {
  const tableMap = {};
  arrayTest.map((arrayItem) => {
    const { table } = arrayItem;
    if (!tableMap[table.id]) {
      tableMap[table.id] = table;
    }
  });

  arrayTest.map((arrayItem) => {
    const { table } = arrayItem;
    const { join_with } = table;
    if (join_with) {
      const joinedTables = [];
      join_with.split(",").map((joinTabledId) => {
        if (tableMap[joinTabledId]) {
          joinedTables.push(tableMap[joinTabledId].name);
        }
      });
      if (joinedTables.length > 0) {
        joinedTables.map((tableName) => {
          console.log(
            `Table ${table.id} has been joined with table: ${tableName}`
          );
        });
      }
    }
  });
};

tableRelatedNames();
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo comentado usando un `switch`, ya solo lo adpatas a lo que necesites.

```js
let arrayTest=[
{"table":{"id":1,"name":"Mesa Alta","capacity":4,"join_with":"2"}},
{"table":{"id":2,"name":"Mesa media","capacity":6,"join_with":"3"}},
{"table":{"id":3,"name":"Mesa baja","capacity":10,"join_with":"2,1"}}
]

for(var i = 0; i < arrayTest.length; i++){
    
    var id = parseInt(arrayTest[i]['table']['id']);
    
    switch(id){
        case 1://busca con un solo id en join_with
            var mesa_unida = parseInt( arrayTest[i]['table']['join_with']) - 1//le resta 1 para ubicar bien la posicion de la mesa en el array
            var mesa = arrayTest[i]['table']['name'];//obtiene el nombre de la mesa original
            
            console.log(mesa+" unida con "+ arrayTest[mesa_unida]['table']['name']);//imprime la mesa unida
            break;
            
        case 2://busca con un solo id en join_with
            var mesa_unida = parseInt( arrayTest[i]['table']['join_with']) - 1//le resta 1 para ubicar bien la posicion de la mesa en el array
            var mesa = arrayTest[i]['table']['name'];//obtiene el nombre de la mesa original
            
            console.log(mesa+" unida con "+ arrayTest[mesa_unida]['table']['name']);//imprime la mesa unida
            break;
            
        case 3://busca con varios id en join_with
            var id_mesas = arrayTest[i]['table']['join_with'];//obtiene los ids
            id_mesas = id_mesas.replace(/,/g,"");//reemplaza las comas
            
            var mesa = arrayTest[i]['table']['name'];//obtiene el nombre de la mesa original
            var mensaje = " unida con: ";//mensaje que se construirá
            
            for(var j = 0; j < id_mesas.length; j++){//recorre ids
                 var aux_id = parseInt( id_mesas[j]) - 1;//le resta 1 para ubicar bien la posicion de la mesa en el array
 
                 var mesa_unida = arrayTest[aux_id]['table']['name'];//obtiene el nombre de la mesa unida de acuerdo a la posicion de aux_id
                 mensaje += mesa_unida + ", ";//construye el mensaje que se mostrará
            }
            console.log(mesa + mensaje);//imprime las mesas unidas
            break;
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yo antes de solucionarlo, hice un pequeño cambio, ya que el objeto 'table' no es necesario, porque igualmente dentro de él estas metiendo solamente otro objeto.

Dicho esto, el array quedaría así:

```
let arrayTest = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Mesa Alta',
    capacity: 4,
    join_with: '2'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mesa media',
    capacity: 6,
    join_with: 'null'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Mesa baja',
    capacity: 10,
    join_with: '1,2'
  }
]
```

Ahora, lo primero será que debemos dividir cada elemento del "join_with" y colocarlo dentro de un array, para poder hacer validaciones con cada elemento, pero lo haremos solo sí lo que está en "join_with" es distinto de "null", esto lo haremos así:

```
const splitedArray = arrayTest.map((table) => {
  const splitedJoin =
    table.join_with === 'null' ? table.join_with : table.join_with.split(',') //sí es igual a null, no dividimos el array, solo devolvemos null. De lo contrario, agregamos los valores de join_with dentro de un array. Omitimos las comas.

  const splitedTable = { //Cambiamos cada join_with por el valor de la variable splited_join
    ...table,
    join_with: splitedJoin
  }
  return splitedTable //Retornamos el nuevo objeto con los cambios hechos
})
```

Ya no usaremos el array del inicio, solo este con los cambios del "join_with". Ahora es la parte complicada, validar cuales mesas están unidas a una mesa. Yo lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
splitedArray.forEach((table) => {
  const tables_joined = [] //Aqui estarán las mesas que estén dentro del array join_with. Tendrá a cuales mesas esta unida cada mesa

  if (table.join_with !== 'null') { //Solo hacemos la validación sí join_with no es null

    table.join_with.forEach((id_joined) => {//recorremos cada elemento dentro del join_with para validarlo con el id de cada mesa

      splitedArray.map((table_id) => {//recorremos de nuevo las mesas para conseguir su id

        if (id_joined === table_id.id.toString()) {//validamos sí el id de cada mesa está dentro del array de join_with. El id de cada mesa lo pasamos a string, porque join_with es un array de strings
          tables_joined.push(table_id)//Sí está, lo ingresamos al array tables_joined
        }

      })
    })
  }

  tables_joined.forEach((table_joined) => {//Recorremos el array que tiene a cuales mesas esta unida cada mesa, y las imprimimos
    console.log(
      `La mesa ${table.id} esta unida con la mesa: ${table_joined.name}`
    )
  })
})
```

Lo importante es saber que en el array "tables_joined" están las mesas a las que esta unida cada mesa, con eso, puedes hacer lo que necesitas.

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.